# How can I get all Actions for a Board using Trello's Rest API?

Tags: rest, api, trello, pagination

I want to get all the actions for a board, but Trello limits the results to 1000. I understand the correct way to deal with this is to paginate. I've tried both `before` and `page` as keywords:

**Basic Call:**

```
https://api.trello.com/1/board/[boardID]/
         ?key=[key]&token=[token]
         &actions=commentCard&actions_limit=1000
```

**Alternatives:**

**`Before`:**

```
https://api.trello.com/1/board/[boardID]/
         ?key=[key]&token=[token]
         &actions=commentCard&actions_limit=1000&
         before=[oldest_returned_action's_date]
```

**`Page`:**

```
https://api.trello.com/1/board/[boardID]/
         ?key=[key]&token=[token]
         &actions=commentCard&actions_limit=1000&
         page=[page_number]
```

The result never varies --- I always get back [limit] number of actions, and they're always the same no matter the call. I checked the dates in what was returned and they certainly don't respect the `before` parameter. I even tried lowering the limit to make sure I wasn't trying to return more than I possessed. The problem persists.

How can I correctly get all actions for a Trello board?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actions are in reverse chronological order (newest-to-oldest), so to page through the actions on a board, you would use something like:

```
curl "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/${BOARD_ID}/actions/?key=${TRELLO_API_KEY}&token=${TRELLO_TOKEN}&limit=1000"
```

then, from the last element of the array returned by the the above, select the `date` or `id` and pass that as the `before` parameter in the next call, e.g.:

```
curl "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/${BOARD_ID}/actions/?key=${TRELLO_API_KEY}&token=${TRELLO_TOKEN}&limit=1000&before=${DATE_OR_ID_OF_LAST_ACTION}"
```

and repeat, passing in either the `id` or `date` of the last action as the subsequent `before` parameter.

#### References:

- [Paging](https://developers.trello.com/docs/api-introduction#section-paging)
- [Board Actions](https://developers.trello.com/reference#boardsboardidactions)
- [Actions Nested Resource](https://developers.trello.com/reference#actions-nested-resource)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this kind of url before but it didn't work for me, but this time yours did! Do you have any idea why? Isn't what I posted in my question supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: It also looks like instead of `&actions=commentCard` as in my question, it now needs to be `&filter=commentCard` for getting card types. Good to know!

Comment: And that limit needs to be `limit=1000`, not `actions_limit=1000`.