# Trello API: How to use 'before' and 'since' action filters in request URI

Tags: api, trello

Hopefully this is a simple syntax problem, but I've tried a number of combinations and nothing seems to work.

I'm wanting to create a simple powershell script to automatically export my Trello Board actions to .JSON.

I can do this fine with:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/<BOARDID>?key=<KEY>&token=<TOKEN>&actions=all&actions_limit=1000"|Set-Content "C:\TrelloBoardActions.json"
```

but the API limits the response to 1000 actions and I want all of them. I understand the solution is to make multiple calls using 'before' and 'since' options to get the full results in batches, but I've not been able to figure out a syntax that will return anything other than the latest actions.

Comment: This exactly same question got a solution on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777063/how-can-i-get-all-actions-for-a-board-using-trellos-rest-api). I was searching for it and worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get all Actions for a Board using Trello's Rest API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777063/how-can-i-get-all-actions-for-a-board-using-trellos-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very clear in the documentation.

You need to set since or before to "YYYY-MM-DD" string. I combine this with the limit=1000, otherwise you only get the default 50 results.

PYTHON:

```
trello.boards.get_action(board_id, since='2022-06-01', limit=1000)
```

URL:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/boardId/actions?key=APIKey&token=APIToken&since=2022-05-31&before=2022-06-01&limit=1000
```